# shell script : find a string by searching inside all the files in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, terminal, find

How do I find a string contained in (possibly multiple) files in a folder including hidden files and subfolders?

I tried this command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "tes1t" -print0 | sed 's,\.\/,,g'
```

But this yielded no results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`grep -Hnr PATTERN .` if your grep supports `-r` (recursive, = `-d recurse`). Note there would be no limit on recursion depths then.

Or try `grep -d skip -Hn PATTERN {,.[!.]}*{,/{,.[!.]}*}`; this should work since grep accepts multiple file arguments. Just throw away the `-d skip` stuff if your version of `grep` doesn't support it. For shells without the brace expansion,  use the manually expanded form `* */* */.[!.]* .[!.]* .[!.]*/* .[!.]*/.[!.]*`.

Comment: You don't need `extglob`.  Just `grep PATTERN .[!.]* * */.[!.]* */*` where `[!.]` specifies "any character except `.`" (so as to prevent going into the parent directory `..`).

Comment: Yes this is one sick answer, great stuff!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `maxdepth` should have been `2` instead of `1`, now your [find](/questions/tagged/find) command won't descend in subdirectories. Furthermore you can simply [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) for your pattern on the output of `find`. This can be achieved as follows:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -exec grep 'pattern here' '{}' \;
```

Explanation:

- `find .` execute `find` in current directory.
- `-maxdepth 2` descend in subdirectories by no further.
- `-type f` find every file that is not a directory.
- `-exec grep 'pattern' '{}'` execute a `grep` statement with a certain pattern, the `{}` contains the filename for each file found.

Add options to grep for color highlighting, outputting line numbers and/or the file name.

For more information see `man find` and `man grep`.

Comment: Or possibly you should not have `-maxdepth` at all if the intent is to traverse subdirectories of subdirectories recursively.  The question is not really clear on this.

Comment: @tripleee true, I just figured the OP wanted to limit the recursion level because he included the option. I will add your remark to the answer, thanks for pointing that out!